# Refreshing page by f5 or reload button without lost the iframe page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Refreshing page by f5 or reload button without lost the iframe page:

Hello!

I'v a webpage that contains a iframe and I want that when refresh button will clicks the iframe stay on currnet page and not back to the defult page.

For exmple:

When I enter to webpage I see an iframe with url google.com and I move in iframe to google.co.il, I want that when I refresh this it will refresh the google.co.il and isn't back to google.com.

tnx very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) makes this impossible.

In order to do what you want you would need to spy on what the user does in the iframe and record changes to the URL somewhere. This is easy enough if the iframe only shows pages that you control.

Since it would be a major security problem to allow someone to spy on what a visitor does on other websites, access to that data is forbidden.

Comment: and change the act of button to refresh iframe when f5 clicked or refresh pag butto is possible?

Comment: @jeamfox — Remember how in the first paragraph of my answer I said that it was impossible? It is still impossible.